# Screenshot is not supported below API 14

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to get a screen shot of the android studio emulator running on API-10. Unfortunately I am getting the following message:

[image]

Can anyone explain why is that so and is there any other easy workaround to this **except Print Screen** (since it does not produce the same image quality and one needs to crop the image manually)?

Comment: you can just take a screenshot of the computer screen or maybe take a look at this http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ashot-handy-screenshot-tool-android-windows/

Comment: You shouldn't vote down before reading the whole question.

Comment: I have already told you "except print screen".

Comment: wasn't me but i still agree with the vote down

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as the link states: "AShot displays what’s on your device on your computer screen", I want to take screen shot of the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been within the Android Studio itself:

1- Click on **Android Device Monitor**

2- On the left, there is a tab named **Devices** . Find your emulator name and click on it.

3- In front of the **Devices** tab there are a set of icons. Find the **Screen Capture** icon and click on it.

4- After the **Device Screen Capture** window opens, wait until your emulator's current screen is captured.

5- At last, you can save the quality image by clicking on the **Save** button.